# PostgreSQL update table from JOIN table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two database tables named `items` and `item_records`. In table `items` there is a field named `current_item_record_id` which is the newest record from `item_records` table.

Here is a sample from two tables:

Table ITEMS:

```
Item ID   |  current_item_record_id    

100                  NULL
```

and 
Table ITEM RECORDS

```
ID    | item_id   | created_at
500     100         2018-01-12 14:48:37
501     100         2018-01-13 14:48:37
501     100         2018-01-14 14:48:37
```

The final result should be LIKE this:

```
Item ID   |  current_item_record_id    

100          500
```

PROBLEM: I need more optimized query to query big table content.

Here is what my query looks like:

```
UPDATE items 
   SET current_item_record_id = (SELECT id 
                                 FROM item_records 
                                 WHERE item_id = items.id 
                                 ORDER BY created_at desc LIMIT 1)  
WHERE items.current_item_record_id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
UPDATE items i
    SET current_item_record_id = (SELECT id
                                  FROM item_records ir
                                  WHERE ir.item_id = i.id
                                  ORDER BY ir.created_at DESC
                                  LIMIT 1)
    WHERE i.current_item_record_id IS NULL;
```

You want indexes on `item_records(item_id, created_at)` and `items(current_item_record_id, id)`.

This should be sufficient for better performance.